# Remove long lines from text file (Notepad++/EditPlus)

Tags: regex, file, text, notepad++, editplus

I have a very big text file.
Every line in  this textfile has a complete sentence in it.
Now I have to remove every line/sentence with more than x characters in it and just keep the lines with <=x characters.

Is this even possible? Can i do this with Notepad++/EditPlus or Regular Expressions?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this in windows or linux?

Comment: Currently in Windows, but I can switch to Linux, if I have to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using bash:

```
$ awk '{if (length($0) <= x) print $0; }'  myfyle.txt
```

Where `x` is the length. It will print the lines smaller than `x`.

See [Awk Tutorial and Introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) for more awk goodies.

Comment: This does not seem to work, yet the up-votes suggest that it should. I created a file with a very large line. However, no matter what the value of x that I put the file will not change. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 9):

**This is solution for Notepad++**

Choose "Regular expression" in Search Mode. Make sure ". matches newline" checkbox is **unchecked**.

Find what: `.{x}.+`

Replace with: (empty)

If you don't want to leave an empty line after replacement:

Find what: `.{x}.+(\r?\n|\n|$)`

Replace `x` with number of your choice.

Comment: @eliahwinkler: You need to check the regular expression option.

Comment: I did. EditPlus doesn't find anything with your string

Comment: @eliahwinkler: It is for Notepad++

Comment: Can't find the text: ".{200}.+(\r?\n|\n|$)"

Same for Notepad++ and EditPlus

Comment: @eliahwinkler: It works fine for me. You need the regular expression mode. And try to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for Editplus version 3.70.

The following will delete any line that is 201 characters or more if you want to keep lines that are <= 200.

- Find what: **^.{201,}.*\n**
- Leave replace with blank
- Check regular expression

Note the comma after the 201.